# Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed

Tags: authentication, ssh, chef-infra

From workstation (Windows) trying to execute

> knife ssh 'name:*' 'sudo chef-client'

But it shows error message of

> WARNING: Failed to connect to ******** – Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ************

How do I solve this error?

Another question is how to execute 'sudo chef-client' on all nodes from workstation without using any passwords?

Answer (score 2):

If you run `knife ssh --help` you'll get a list of available options.  Try adding `-VV` for verbose output.  That's usually helpful as it should tell you what user knife is trying to connect as.

My guess is you'll have to incorporate one or more of the ssh options (a few listed here):

`-x, --ssh-user USERNAME`

`-i, --identity-file IDENTITY_FILE`

`-P, --ssh-password [PASSWORD]` (will prompt if flag specified but no password is given)

The docs (https://docs.getchef.com/knife_ssh.html) also have some helpful examples

Comment: This worked for me.  I had to specify `-x` and `-i`.

Comment: I'm facing this issue because the `--ssh-identity-file` key file being used has a passphrase, and for reasons, using a local key agent is complicated. In this situation, it seems unpossible to get `knife`'s implementation of `Net::SSH` to ask for the key passphrase. Adding either `--ssh-password` (which results in a deprecation warning) or `--connection-password` results in the same failure.  

Answer (score 0):

Your SSH authentication isn't working, fix that. Key-based authentication is something I'm sure you can look up on Google, but in general set your public key in `.ssh/authorized_keys` and setup your agent on your workstation.

Comment: .ssh/authorized_keys , where to find this? and what do you mean by setup your agent on workstation? What steps should I refer?